# Sum up snail number neighbours

Tags: code-golf, math

**Input**: You are given two numbers `n` and `m`.

**Create the snail**: Given an `n >= 3`, fill an `n` * `n` grid with the numbers from `1` to `n * n`, starting at the top left, going clockwise to the middle like this (for `n` = 5):

```
 1  2  3  4  5
16 17 18 19  6
15 24 25 20  7
14 23 22 21  8
13 12 11 10  9
```

**Calculate the sum of the neightbours of `m`**: for `4*n – 4 < m <= n*n`, calculate the sum of the eight neighbour numbers in the snail. In the 5 * 5 example, for `m`= 17, this would be:

```
1+2+3+16+18+15+24+25 = 104
```

**Output**: Only the sum

**Test cases**:

```
4,14 --> 64
5,17 --> 104
5,25 --> 164
6,24 --> 112
6,30 --> 176
6,32 --> 200
6,33 --> 234
```

**Win** by finding the shortest code for your language of choice!

Comment: Are we allowed to use a 0-indexed spiral?

Comment: @Mukundan314 Of course you can; then simply add 8 to the sum to get the correct result. You can even create no spiral at all if you find another way to get the correct sum.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/168949/58563)

Comment: If you say that 0-indexed spirals are allowed, if only by adding 8, then what if the cell m has fewer than 8 neighbors like in the corner?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Each cell m will have eight neighbours.

Comment: @Philippos if `n=1` and `m=1` you don't have 8 neighbors. For your last assumption to always be true you should says that `n>=3` or just say that we assume `m` will always have 8 neighbors.

Comment: @Marius_Couet I added n>=3. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 19 bytes

```
UQG1YL-t3Y6Z+wi=*Xz
```

Try it [at MATL online](https://matl.io/?code=UQG1YL-t3Y6Z%2Bwi%3D%2aXz&inputs=6%0A24&version=22.8.0)!

#### How it works

```
UQ     % Implicit input: n. Square, add 1
G      % Push n again
1YL    % Generate spiral with side length n, from 1 to to n^2 outwards
-      % Subtract, element-wise. The spiral is now from 1 to n^2 inwards
t      % Duplicate
3Y6    % Push predefined literal: [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1]
Z+     % 2D convolution, preserving size. This computes the sums
w      % Swap. This moves the spiral to the top of the stack
i=     % Input: m. Compare for equality, element-wise
*      % Multiply, element-wise. This keeps the wanted sum, and makes the rest 0
Xz     % Nonzeros. This keeps the only non-zero value. Implicit display
```

Comment: This assumes `m` is excluded, as in most of the test cases. To include it, `3` should be replaced by `4`. The code works even if `m` is on the rim of the square (pending clarifications by Philippos)

Comment: m was defined to always having eight neighbours, so your solution even over-targets the question. And it beats my expectations: I hoped I finally found a simple question which can't be solved with a few hand full of bytes, then you did even beat the 05AB1E answer. Congratulations to the clever implementation!

Comment: @Philippos Thanks! Having a spiral builtin (inherited from Matlab) helps :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 31/32<sup>*†*</sup> [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¯I·FāUøí¬g+Xš}2Fø€ü3}€`ʒ˜4èQ}˜O
```

Inputs in the order \$n,m\$.

31 bytes - sum including \$m\$: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf9vc2FiaWX//8KvScK3RsSBVcO4w63CrGcrWMWhfTJGw7jigqzDvDN94oKsYMqSy5w0w6hRfcucT///NQoxNw) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC2P9D64sPbXc70hh6eMfhtYfWpGtHHF1Ya@R2eMejpjWH9xjXAqmEU5NOzzE5vCIysPb0HP//Ov@jo010DE1idaJNdQzNwZSRKZAy0zEyAVPGBhDKCEIZx8YCAA).
32 bytes - sum excluding \$m\$: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUAAv/9vc2FiaWX//8KvScK3RsSBVcO4w63CrGcrWMWhfTJGw7jigqzDvDN94oKsYMqSy5w0w6hRfcucT86x//81CjE3) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXC4QlhRf8PrS8@tN3tSGPo4R2H1x5ak64dcXRhrZHb4R2PmtYc3mNcC6QSTk06Pcfk8IrIwNrTc/zPbfyv8z862kTH0CRWJ9pUx9AcTBmZAikzHSMTMGVsAKGMIJRxbCwA). (Contains an additional trailing `α`.)

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Create the spiral matrix for the given \$n\$, taken from [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241860/52210):

```python
¯             # Start with an empty list []
 I·           # Push the first input n and double it
   F          # Pop and loop that many times:
    ā         #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping the matrix)
     U        #  Pop and store this list in variable `X`
      øí      #  Rotate the matrix 90 degrees clockwise:
      ø       #   Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
       í      #   Reverse each row
        ¬     #  Push the first row (without popping the matrix)
         g    #  Pop and push its length
          +   #  Add that to each value in the matrix
           Xš #  Prepend list `X` as first row
   }          # Close the loop
```

Step 2: Create overlapping 3x3 blocks of this matrix:

```python
2F            # Loop 2 times:
  ø           #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
   €          #  Map over each inner list:
    ü3        #   Create overlapping triplets
 }            # Close the loop
```

Step 3: Only keep the 3x3 block with \$m\$ in the center:

```python
€`            # Flatten the matrix of 3x3 blocks one level down to a list of 3x3 blocks
  ʒ           # Filter this list by:
   ˜          #  Flatten the 3x3 block to a list of 9 values
    4è        #  Pop and leave the 0-based 4th item (the center)
      Q       #  Check whether it equals the second (implicit) input m
  }           # Close the filter
```

Step 4: Sum the found 3x3 block, and output the result:

```python
˜             # Flatten the single wrapped 3x3 block to a list
 O            # Sum it together
  α           # (optionally) Take the absolute difference with the second (implicit)
              # input m to subtract m from this sum
              # (after which this is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 116 bytes

```r
\(n,k){m=t(1)
while(F<n)m=rbind(1:n,(F=nrow(m))+t(m[F:1,]))
sum(m[t(t(expand.grid(-1:1,-1:1))+c(which(m==k,T)))])-k}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc1LDoIwEADQPacgcTMTW8MUREOsS07gTlmogBJsNViCifEkbtDEQ3kbkc9mJvPm93wV9TuVn9KkfP41G9Asx7uSBgit6pidEggXGpUsdpmOgQLNIJS6OFegEMcG1DoMiEWI1rVUTWXAQHK7bHU8ORRZDJya9j8003toLu6PoKTM2QoRI-T5o_9dpuAx8nBkc760fc9KYcpo1tckqAUxHaCd8JkYNohEC64zwMzvQPQgHKcDdwDX657XdZd_)

Uses some code from the [spiral challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241886/55372).

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```
([-~1#.]#&,~[:+/(>,{;~i:1)|.=)+:@<:_&(]#\,#+|:@|.),.@1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BisIwEIbvPsVgwCY0TpOm7cJopLjgSTx4rVVEKquXXYi3lr56beouWw8Dwzf//829m2JwBUsQgAQF1M8c4XO/3XS8mLeaYclmsi0ojPhK1ov2Rlo0aEVI@ZJOM16yg2RhQ3mDQmKuOzHZrRG4qlVdMi@woiAZGTA8jCJsU8sOIpcLPJnB8WY4UuElk@ry9Q36A66QvvbgUbkHXM6ucsA1WPg5OyeC1zFLeqCTPp38NtVARn09ZOJ0RHTsiW9lf/@ynhj1T2KlPIlHxHiPMZ50Tw)

Uses [Bubbler's clever APL/Jelly method from an old problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241837/15469) for constructing the involute itself.

Consider input `17 f 5`:

- `+:@<:_&(]#\,#+|:@|.),.@1` Construct the involute iteratively using Bubbler's method (see link above for explanation):

  ```
  1  2  3  4 5
  16 17 18 19 6
  15 24 25 20 7
  14 23 22 21 8
  13 12 11 10 9
  ```
- `=` Where does the left input equal that?

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `[:+/(>,{;~i:1)|.` Rotate that in the 8 neighbor directions, and sum the planes:

  ```
  1 1 1 0 0
  1 1 1 0 0
  1 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `1#.]#&,~` Filter using that mask and sum:

  ```
  121
  ```
- `[-~` Subtract the left input (17):

  ```
  104
  ```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 60/62 bytes

```
Ｆ⊗Ｎ≔⁺⟦Ｅυ⊕λ⟧Ｅ∧υ⌊υ⁺ＬυＥ⮌υ§μλυＮθ≔⊟Φυ№ιθηＩΣＥΦυ‹↔⁻κ⌕υη²ΣΦι‹↔⁻μ⌕ηθ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY49awMxDIb3/AqPMrhDAyVDpiMlcJCUkI6lw32osYk/LrYV@u@vspPQDl0Ekt5HegbdxSF0dp6/QhTwGqi3OELrJ8pv5HqMIKUUTUrm5OFgKcHHvpuAlGj9ENGhz5y3Un4qURaNH8tyb7xx5ICkVKJiO/SnrHlwyx3xijFh7Zvc@hG/wSnBh2RBSK4XfyUu3D8kwgRbYzNP@dEmkM9glLhUTnPuEA2PNl3K8M4K5dtvfocpQdOnYCkjsCarnZXYmpu3rleWpRT2zpn/OXfn9OP7strL9Ty/LJ5X89PV/gA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⊗Ｎ≔⁺⟦Ｅυ⊕λ⟧Ｅ∧υ⌊υ⁺ＬυＥ⮌υ§μλυ
```

Input `n` and generate the spiral using the method from my answer to [Print a NxN integer involute](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241803/) except 1-indexed.

```
Ｎθ≔⊟Φυ№ιθη
```

Input `m` and find the row containing `m` in the spiral.

```
ＩΣＥΦυ‹↔⁻κ⌕υη²ΣΦι‹↔⁻μ⌕ηθ²
```

Extract the neighbours of `m` and output the sum.

Note that the `5, 17` test case includes the `17` itself in the total; if this is not wanted then it can be subtracted at a cost of 2 bytes:

```
Ｆ⊗Ｎ≔⁺⟦Ｅυ⊕λ⟧Ｅ∧υ⌊υ⁺ＬυＥ⮌υ§μλυＮθ≔⊟Φυ№ιθηＩ⁻ΣＥΦυ‹↔⁻κ⌕υη²ΣΦι‹↔⁻μ⌕ηθ²θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY49awMxDIb3/AqPMrhDA6VDpiMlcJCU0I6lw32osYk/LrYV@u@vsnOhHboI6dX7SO@guziEzs7zV4gCXgL1Fkdo/UT5lVyPEaSUoknJnDwcLSX4OHQTkBKtHyI69Jn9VspPJcqi8WNZHow3jhyQlEpUbI/@lDULN98bXjEmrHOTWz/iNzgl@JAsCMnN6m@IC8/3EGGCnbGZVX60DeQzGCUuldPsO0bD0rZLGTgGv37nIOXnL7XHlKDpU7CUcXGdldiZW3pdb61LKezCmf85t3D6nmFda@k38/y0enyeH672Bw) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 174 bytes

Derived from [this answer by tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241832/58563) to [this other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241803/58563).

Expects `(n)(m)`.

```javascript
n=>m=>(g=(s,[l]=t=s[0])=>l>1?g([0,...t].map((_,i)=>s.map((r,x)=>(v=r[i-1]||--l)-m?v:(X=x,Y=i,v)).reverse())):s)([[n*n]]).map((r,y)=>r.map(v=>m-=v*=--x*x+y*y<3,x=n-X,y-=Y))|-m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7RaoQwEIXh@z7JjM0EXd0Wlo77GruEUGSbFUuMSyIhgu9uQ0svSr38v4HDfHaxCzc/PGZy04fZ7rw5bkduoWcIQlnNMwdVauTWttW5B1UKKeWs5dg9AN7FkC/hJ7xIOSCyVwNVel2JLNJ4jie4cBJXHkRElN5E44MBRDwFBKVc4bTG340lb/jviPkT4lgwUSrS81Isb7VI7OgiFuIr4krjdptcmKyRdurhDg1C1SA@/dVj1tc9PRz/6UvWZk/rclcPu1ojbl8)

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 423 bytes

Assuming \$n\$ is in A1 and \$m\$ is in A2.

```cpp
=SUMPRODUCT(LET(n,A1,s,SEQUENCE(n,n),t,TOCOL(SPLIT(REDUCE(s,s,LAMBDA(x,_,LET(r,INDEX(x,1),a,FILTER(x,r),HSTACK(JOIN(",",r),SORT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(a,"offset 1")),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(a)),))))),","),3),p,XLOOKUP(s,{t;INDEX(t,n*n-1)+IF(ISODD(n),1,-1)},TOCOL(s)),x,TEXTJOIN(,,IF(p=A2,SEQUENCE(n)&","&SEQUENCE(1,n),)),i,SPLIT(x,","),r,INDEX(i,1),k,INDEX(i,2),p*MAKEARRAY(n,n,LAMBDA(i,j,ISBETWEEN(i,r-1,r+1)*ISBETWEEN(j,k-1,k+1)))))-A2
```

Ungolfed

````cpp
// Create the spiral

=LET(n,A1,s,SEQUENCE(n,n),
     t,TOCOL(
         SPLIT(REDUCE(s,s,LAMBDA(x,_, 
           LET(r,INDEX(x,1),a,FILTER(x,r),
               HSTACK(JOIN(",",r),
               SORT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(a,"offset 1")),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(a)),))))),
           ","),3),
     p,XLOOKUP(s,{t;INDEX(t,n*n-1)+IF(ISODD(n),1,-1)},TOCOL(s)),

// Find the coordinates of m 

     x,TEXTJOIN(,,IF(p=A2,SEQUENCE(n)&","&SEQUENCE(1,n),)),

// Assign them to (r,k)  

     i,SPLIT(x,","),r,INDEX(i,1),k,INDEX(i,2),
 
// Create a nxn array composed of 1s in the 3x3 array around (r,k) and 0s everywhere else and multiply it by the spiral

     p*MAKEARRAY(n,n,LAMBDA(i,j,ISBETWEEN(i,r-1,r+1)*ISBETWEEN(j,k-1,k+1))))


// Array enabling sum on the above result to which we subtract m

SUMPRODUCT(all_of_the_above)-A2
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 47 bytes

```
-:/+♭⍜↻(↙3_3)-1♭⊚⌕⊙.:+1⍥(⊂⇡⟜(≡⇌⍉+)⧻.):¤[]-1+.⊙.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAgLTovK-KZreKNnOKGuyjihpkzXzMpLTHima3iiprijJXiipkuOisx4o2lKOKKguKHoeKfnCjiiaHih4zijYkrKeKnuy4pOsKkW10tMSsu4oqZLgoKZiA0IDE0CmYgNSAxNwpmIDUgMjUKZiA2IDI0CmYgNiAzMApmIDYgMzIKZiA2IDMzCg==)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Could you please add some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 106 bytes

Prompts for n followed by m:

```
a←1 1⍴1⋄i←1⋄⍎∊(¯1+n←⎕)⍴⊂'a←(⍳i+1)⍪⌽⍉(i+1)+(⍳i)⍪⌽⍉a+i⋄i←i+1⋄'⋄+/((,a)[(k-n),(k+n),(k←((,a)⍳m)+¯1 0 1)])~m←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##RY47CsJAEIb7OUW67LIGs3noGQTFA4jFEomEPBRS2ViIaIwm2HgJGwttbTzKXCTOJoLFzvfPv/NS68RabFSyWlpBovI8Chqsb5MxHq4ukBpNSUnA4hg2SktDYvWSeN5HOiNiVWNRss9Diows6uFUgeXO1PUMq2ckJFl3vLyxOjGdidb@m0pEv4n0S8qkJ/qM9RSfsdjKeI/Foo16pLapP@WClhq2Ifmcb9Nud0OXQhOCB9IzIAQf5LCF4xMG4HgtXLuD08H9Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 137 bytes

```javascript
n=>h=(v,i,j=n,g=(x=i,y=j,w=n,h=w)=>y?w+g(y-1,w+~x,h-1,w):x+1)=>j--?h(v,i,j)+(1/i?(v.i-i)**2+(v.j-j)**2<3?g():g()==v&&h({i,j})-v:h(v,j)):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxRDoIwDED/PQhp2YaCoMm0cBaCwLYQZsQMiNGr44h/6keT19e8mtKVQ3XT17vo7aVeGlp6yhWB45ob6nlLMJHmMxk@@lXRiJTPxchamEXMR/aauFoB5cRifzNCFOqTI4N4qwtwkRYawzBhHo0wK573RQso/RC5IFDw8METhZNrbBDlbjltKtsPtqujzrbQQIoQp4hfNvP2@M8m2Y89eOs/LG8)

`g()` gets the number at position `(x,y)`

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>216 212</strike> 193 bytes

```
func f(){r=$2-(g[x,y]=++c)?r:-g[m=x,n=y]}{for(x=y=0;i++<$1;y++)f();for(y--;s++<$1;){for(i=s;i++<$1;)f(x+=t=s%2?1:-1);for(i=s;i++<$1;)f(y-=t)}for(i=m-2;++i<m+2;)for(j=n-1;j<n+2;)r+=g[i,j++]}$0=r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BbsIwEEX3nMJCrpQwWPI4birFGVj3DFEWiBLktHGRCW0ilLOndimLLth9/f/ezO77feZYZteTt65ny1f3tfuwb8y606VnBXNltjTuMPTTQq84Cr0hrh7BeuUi0N0NrjYcg/WI7zZu5f7gubm4PWuS9OrDB5Ecq2E91gSwT7e@EMeqo2HtaKyna/Ppk4FGksYClBzNCJAG08RhFMKcb3X6S1o637kADUA9nZ/UFguBN@M/MArq0@nWd0IZAFt2oMIUqpacQNOWLhYe6FjZdQtQT1ySnz3tKRwjOWuGmuV68czwhaGMQYUcmpypMKIKIZNhzWNQTEkZQ8ZUphcYvajkPw)

- -4 bytes, used ternary operator (`exp?a:b`) instead of `if` statement and replaced `==` with `-` expression.
- -19 bytes, replaced ternary operation with function.

Comment: [184 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY5LboMwFEXnrMKKHAljrPpXqgYeHXcNiEFECrJa3MiQFoRYO7WbZtBBZlf3nvPs4/f7hkWhlrMzdkS7V/t1/DAnZOz5MqIDsoXa5fZtGtdIJ1gwXQKW92Cd2AD0NwPLEgtv3eP70ib2D97ai21QG5PF@RdY3FVTOtdAaUNe3IF1VQ9TamGu16X9dPEEM/DcUFpgkc@UEm/mYZgZy4drTX5JA8ON89BEYYRhLxPJxFX4v88MRrJe@@fc@GPEUegq///YPChCeyZSs1fUMlGvmIPbHDTgjwDfNBIaZTp6ROIJCR6C9Nk3GZJ@FNIHxf2ahSCR5DwEhaTSkQheULIf "AWK – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

**[Q](https://code.kx.com/q/), 169 Bytes**

**Golfed:**

```
b:1 0 -1 0;d:0;c:0 0;s:n#(,)n#0;a:{c+{x d}'[(0,b;b)]};{.[`s;c;:;x];if[x=m;l::c];if[0<>.[s;n:a[]];d::mod[d+1;4];n:a[]];c::n}'[1+til n*n];sum[(s/')[(cross/){x+3#b}'[l]]]-m
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
snail: n#enlist n#0;   // create an n x n array (the "snail") where each cell has value 0; it's populated properly below
direction: 0;          // 0=right, 1=down, 2=left, 3=up 
current_cell: 0 0;     // the row/column of the current cell to populate in the n x n array
m_cell: -1 -1;         // the row/column of the cell in the n x n array whose value is m

// given a 2-item list returns the value of the snail cell at the row & column; returns null (0N) if there is no such row or column
read_cell: { .[snail; x] };

// returns the row + index (2-item list) of the cell after "current_cell" that should be populated given the current value of "direction"
get_next_cell: { (current_cell[0] + (0 1 0 -1)[direction]; current_cell[1] + (1 0 -1 0)[direction]) };

// loop through integers in range [1..n x n] to populate the snail
{
    // set value of current_cell in the snail to the current integer in the loop
    snail:: .[snail; current_cell; :; x];
    
    // record m_cell if the current integer in the loop is "m
    if[x=m; m_cell:: current_cell];

    // calculate the next cell
    next_cell: get_next_cell[];

    // if the calculated next cell has a non-zero value, either:
    //      * the value is 0N, meaning we've gone past the bounds of the n x n array or
    //      * the value is a positive integer, meaning the cell has already been populated
    // in which case we change direction and re-calculate the next cell
    if[read_cell[next_cell] <> 0;
        direction:: (direction + 1) mod 4;
        next_cell: get_next_cell[];
        ];

    current_cell:: next_cell;
    } each 1+til n*n;

// "return" the difference between (a) the sum of all 9 cells in the 3x3 square centered on m_cell and (b) m
sum[read_cell each .[cross]{x + -1 0 1} each m_cell] - m
```